# How to close a socket connection of other application?

Tags: .net, winapi

Similarly to what TCPView can do.

Are there any ways to do it in .net or in winapi?

I need to automate this process to simulate connection lost for my integration tests.

Also, I cannot use http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html since it's blocked by my company.

Comment: Close a TCP connection by port -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672062/how-to-close-a-tcp-connection-by-port

Comment: Thanks, @RossBush, I think this question is a duplicate of the one you've provided. Will check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now when a program wants to create a socket, it creates a process that listens to a pre-defined port of choice.

As mentioned in this thread [Manually close a port from commandline](https://superuser.com/questions/127863/manually-closing-a-port-from-commandline), the socket is bound to the process that created it. Meaning it would automatically be freed, when the process terminates. With I guess cports (the program you referred) esentially does.

Now you could use the built-in program in windows "netstat" to get a list of reserved ports, and the id of processes that keeps them open.

Take a look at this link [Check Open TCP/IP Ports in Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28609/how-can-i-tell-what-is-listening-on-a-tcpip-port-in-windows/).

There are multiple ways to run a program, and then get the 'std output' for further processing. Here's a link that shows how [Execute a Command in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25983/How-to-Execute-a-Command-in-C).

Summary: (My immediate approach would be...)
Make a call from C# to netstat, get the id, from the port of your interest. And the call "Taskkill /PID the_id /F".

Give it a try, hope it works for you.

Comment: You don't need to spawn a `netstat` process, you can enumerate the connections and owner PIDs directly by using `GetTcpTable2()` or `GetExtendedTcpTable()` instead

Comment: That's also a good way to do it. And probably with a smaller overhead.

Comment: This isn't about overhead as much as it is about correctness. The layout of the structures used by the API calls is well defined. The layout and formatting of the `netstat` tool isn't. There are no implied or expressed guarantees, that the latter won't change, without notice.